# Why is a &str called a slice in Rust?

Tags: rust

It makes me think that it's a substring of some of other string when it's just a stack-allocated string. Do I have the wrong understanding of it?

Comment: I think you do. take a look at the [rust docs regarding strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html)

Comment: Indeed, string slices are called that way because they can refer to substrings of strings somewhere in memory. It's the same as for general slices, which refer to parts of arrays.

Answer (score 18):

> when it's just a stack-allocated string

This is not completely correct. A string slice (`&str`) is conceptually built of two things:

1. A pointer to the beginning of a string.
2. The number of bytes in the string.

The pointer may reference data on the stack, on the heap, or even in the constant program data.

It's called a *string slice* because it mirrors a regular slice (`&[T]`), which is the same two parts: a pointer and a length.

Under the hood, a string is a slice of `u8` (`&[u8]`) but it has a very important guarantee: the sequence of bytes is valid UTF-8.

> a substring of some of other string

Note that you can take the "entire substring" or "entire slice" of something, it doesn't have to be *strictly smaller*. For example:

```
let test_scores = [0, 10, 100];
let all_scores = &test_scores[..]; // or &test_scores[0..3]
let some_scores = &test_scores[0..1];
```